# pandas set value of columns as values of other columns if text length condition is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas

Data looks like this:

```
df
idx    column1                column2
0       text(100 words)         text
1       text(20 words)          text
2       text(30 words)          text
3.      text(500 ords)          text
```

I need something like this:

```
df
idx    column1                column2
0       text(100 words)         text
1       text(20 words)          text(20 words)
2       text(30 words)          text(30 words)
3.      text(500 words)         text
```

I need to replace the value of column2 whenever the text length value of column1 is lower than 50 words.

The idea of what i'd like to do is `where (len(df.column1.str.split()) <= 50) set value of column2 to the value of column1`.

What i've done so far is:

```
df.loc[len(df.column1.str.split()) <= 50, 'column2'] = df['column1']
```

and

```
mask = (len(df['column1'].str.split()) <= 50)
df['column2'][mask] = df['column1']
```

But it's not working properly. In both cases it raises the following error: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'. Any suggestions?

Comment: hi paolo; kindly share sample data with expected output. no pics, just data.

Comment: I did it now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
df.loc[df.column1.str.len() < 50, 'column2'] = df.column1
```

### Example with data after OP's comments:

```
In [624]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[624]: 
           column1 column2
0  text(100 words)    text
1  text(200 words)       t
2   text(10 words)       r
3   text(40 words)       q
```

Assuming the length to be <15 for simplicity of my dataset

```
In [637]: df.loc[df.column1.str.len() < 15, 'column2'] = df.column1                                                                                                                                         

In [638]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[638]: 
           column1         column2
0  text(100 words)            text
1  text(200 words)               t
2   text(10 words)  text(10 words)
3   text(40 words)  text(40 words)
```

So, you can see that the last 2 rows in column2 have been replaced by the value of column1 as their length was < 15.

Comment: This is not working, i've put an example with data to be more clear.

Comment: I pasted my code with working data-set. Please check. It works fine.

Comment: i don't know why but it's not working. Probably something wrong with the data. I'm checking it right now.

Comment: In your code aren't you counting the actual characters in the string instead of the number of the words? In my real df i have texts in some cases really big. I need to count the words so I do len(df.column1.str.split()). but it raises the error: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'.

Comment: Share an example of a string that you have. I will check.

Comment: they are mostly news articles text or tweets. Can't paste them here cause too long. When i run your code it doesn't change anything in my df. When I change your code like this ```df.loc[len(df.column1.str.split()) < 50, 'column2'] = df.column1``` it raises the error 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'

Comment: That's weird. In my understanding, the text in column1 is all strings right? My code should work. Can you please attach a screen-shot of a few-rows of your df?

Comment: With strings i intend full articles body. ```df.column1.str.len()``` is counting the characters of the string not the words in it. In my case the strings are full articles text, with multiple words, separated by spaces. I need to count the words in the article, that's why i was suggesting to use split(), but it raises the error cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'.